# Can GNU-Make's automatic variables be scoped to the current recipe definition only?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) created by GNU-Make are quite handy  for some scenarios:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

%-processed.md: $$(wildcard $$*.m4) $(wildcard macros/*.m4) %.md
    m4 $^ > $@
```

However this idilic world blows up when somebody tries to add on a dependency somewhere else in the makefile:

```
.PHONY: force
force: ;

mybook-processed.md: force
```

Now all of a sudden `m4` complains that "force" isn't a valid input file. Which of course it's not, but its showing up in the `$^` variable because it got appended to the list of prerequisites.

Is there a way to access only the prerequisites defined in the immediate recipe definition while ignoring other ones?

Comment: Note GNU Make 4.3 added a new variable `.EXTRA_PREREQS` that might be coerced into accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible.  That information is not even available in make's internal structures.

Your example solution is not one I'd use though.  If your command only accepts certain types of files, I would use `filter` to ensure that it sees only those types of files:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

%-processed.md: $$(wildcard $$*.m4) $(wildcard macros/*.m4) %.md
        m4 $(filter %.m4 %.md,$^) > $@
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my example was heavily simplified for the sake of asking the question and this won't map directly to a solution, but its still a useful paradigm I wasn't aware of. I see a lot of Makefile refactoring in my future.

Answer (score 1):

You could adopt a naming convention for pseudo-targets like `force`, say `MAGIC/force`.  Then `$(filter-out MAGIC/%,$^)` -- still a little repetitive, but not that bad.

Comment: This is fine if all you add is pseudo-targets.  But maybe you need to have other non-source items as prerequisites: scripts which force a rebuild if changed, maybe even you want to rely on `m4` itself in case it changes.  Etc.  IMO it's more robust to select exactly what you want, rather than trying to get rid of all the different things you might not want.

Answer (score 0):

So far the only way I've found to do this is stop using automatic variables and compose my own. I'm really hoping somebody posites a better answer, but here's my current solution:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

process_prereqs = $(wildcard $1.m4) $(wildcarad macros/*.m4)
%-processed.md: %.md $$(call process_prereqs,$$*)
    m4 $(call process_prereqs,$$*) $< > $@
```

This way only the more stable `$<` automatic variable is used and the other is more predicable, but the code is somewhat repetitive.